# Implementing dynamic compilation in an interpreter

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

I am building an interpreter in C# of a python-like language.
Currently, my interpreter performs the following:

1. Lexical Analysis
2. Parsing
3. Intermediate Code Generation (Byte-code)

And everything works perfectly fine, except I'm faced with the problem of incredible speed drops during CPU-intensive operations (loops, e.t.c.)

I have decided that one of the solutions would be to use something similar to dynamic compilation, so that bytecode can be converted to some other form of code (C# code, machine code).

One potential solution would be considering to use CodeDOM to generate equivalent C# code during runtime, but would it be much faster? what is the overhead involved?

I'm afraid my question might be too broad, please comment and I'll edit.

Comment: Do you know the Irony project?

Comment: Indeed it is too broad... And likely can't be narrowed in current form. Here are 2 potential path you can take - profile your current code and find why it is slow, use Expression Tree to build code (as it is easier than CodeDOM/manual IL). To answer your "much faster?" question - simply find C# REPL and try it out to compare.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @AlexeiLevenkov, I'll look into potential solutions.

Comment: Just use `System.Reflection.Emit` directly, instead of your custom bytecode.

Comment: @SK-logic, interesting idea.